# Including cstring in extern "C" returns conflicting types erros

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I have very simple code like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
extern "C"
{
#include <cstring>
}
int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

When I try to build it with clang++ it returns errors:

```
clang++ test.cpp 
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstring:100:3: error: conflicting types for 'memchr'
  memchr(void* __s, int __c, size_t __n)
  ^
/usr/include/string.h:90:14: note: previous declaration is here
extern void *memchr (const void *__s, int __c, size_t __n)
             ^
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstring:104:3: error: conflicting types for 'strchr'
  strchr(char* __s, int __n)
  ^
/usr/include/string.h:225:14: note: previous declaration is here
extern char *strchr (const char *__s, int __c)
             ^
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstring:108:3: error: conflicting types for 'strpbrk'
  strpbrk(char* __s1, const char* __s2)
  ^
/usr/include/string.h:302:14: note: previous declaration is here
extern char *strpbrk (const char *__s, const char *__accept)
             ^
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstring:112:3: error: conflicting types for 'strrchr'
  strrchr(char* __s, int __n)
  ^
/usr/include/string.h:252:14: note: previous declaration is here
extern char *strrchr (const char *__s, int __c)
             ^
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstring:116:3: error: conflicting types for 'strstr'
  strstr(char* __s1, const char* __s2)
  ^
/usr/include/string.h:329:14: note: previous declaration is here
extern char *strstr (const char *__haystack, const char *__needle)
             ^
5 errors generated.
```

When I move the `#include <cstring>` outside the `extern "C"` program compiles without any issues. The cstring is C header so what is the reason that I shouldn't put this include in extern "C"?

Comment: Try include `string.h`

Comment: Seems to be working fine here https://godbolt.org/z/Y5G5f4

Comment: Why use c headers in a c++ program?

Comment: You don't need `extern "C"` around your inclusion of `<cstring>`.

Comment: _The cstring is C header_ No, it's not - have a look at the [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00830_source.html). Usually C headers have a ".h" extension.

Comment: You should **never** put `extern "C"` around a `#include` directive. If a C++ header was designed to produce code that can be linked with C code it will already have that. If it wasn't designed to produce code that can be linked with C code adding `extern "C"` isn't sufficient.

Comment: the <cstring> makes little sense, it should at least be <string.h>, which in itslef also is not all that useful either.

Comment: @anastaciu No, why?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, why what, the <cstring> comment?

Comment: @anastaciu Yes, the C++ header `<cstring>` is what is prefered in a C++ program since it puts the exported functions in `std` - Some implementations puts them in the global namespace as well, but ... details :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, agreed, but IDK the goal of this code, if you're going to, say, make a dll to be usable in C and C++ it must be <string.h>.

Comment: @anastaciu You don't need to include `string.h` to be able to use those  functions in a DLL - even if the consumers are C programs. What matters in that case is that the functions your DLL exposes have C linkage.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes, the code is pointless, I was just wondering if the OP ends up using `cstring` in some C code, that isn't clear by the discription. And the shown code compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

"*The `cstring` is C header so what is the reason that I shouldn't put this include in extern "C"?*"

No, it's a **C++ header** but you break it by putting it in an `extern "C"` block. C++ headers are never supposed to be included in a block claiming that functions have C linkage even if some, or all, functions have C linkage. The C++ header will make sure the appropriate linkage for every function is properly declared.

Your particular problem seems to occur when using `clang 3.4.1` with the `gcc 8` `cstring` header.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zGGdEz)

In your case, the implementation specific `__CORRECT_ISO_CPP_STRING_H_PROTO` stays undefined, so the compiler reaches a block of `inline` function definitions that it's not supposed to reach which is what causes the conflicting declarations.

The reached block of inline functions:

```
#ifndef __CORRECT_ISO_CPP_STRING_H_PROTO
  inline void*
  memchr(void* __s, int __c, size_t __n)           // gcc 8 cstring line 100
  { return __builtin_memchr(__s, __c, __n); }

  inline char*
  strchr(char* __s, int __n)
  { return __builtin_strchr(__s, __n); }

  inline char*
  strpbrk(char* __s1, const char* __s2)
  { return __builtin_strpbrk(__s1, __s2); }

  inline char*
  strrchr(char* __s, int __n)
  { return __builtin_strrchr(__s, __n); }

  inline char*
  strstr(char* __s1, const char* __s2)
  { return __builtin_strstr(__s1, __s2); }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote, `<cstring>` is not a C header, but a C++ header.  It provides the features of C's `<string.h>`, adding them to the `std::` namespace.

Your application should instead do one of the following:

- Use `<string.h>` (maybe in `extern "C"`, if your compiler requires it) and call the C functions:

```
extern "C" {
#include <string.h>
}
...
strcpy(...);   // Or whatever your app requires
```

- Use `<cstring>` without `extern "C"` and use the `std::` namespace:

```
#include <cstring>
...
std::strcpy(...);  // Or whatever your app requires
```

- Consider refactoring your application to use C++ string objects and don't use the C string functions at all.  But this may not be practical depending on the circumstances of your application.